# pd.concat gets rid of multi-index when axis is set to axis=1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to concatenate four dataframes with identical indexes but different Multi-indexed columns.

When I use:
`df = pd.concat([df_wa, df_avg, df_sum, df_count], sort=False)`

and then write to excel, the DataFrame prints the Multi Index with the first index on the top row of Excel and the other index as the row below.

> cash ... fees ... apr
>
> WA  ...         count ... avg

However, the axis needs to be set as axis=1 so that the indexes don't repeat for every new dataframe. So i use:

`df = pd.concat([df_wa, df_avg, df_sum, df_count], axis=1, sort=False)`

But then I lose the multi index as it is converted to a tuple.

> (free_cash_flow, WA)  ...  (fees_received, count)....(apr, avg)

I have tried to use levels, keys, and unstack with no success. Any idea how to un-flatten the index?

Answer (score 0):

if you set the multi-index using df.columns = multidex values it works out fine. They just have to have the same number of levels

example:

```
array1 = ['animal', 'animal']
array2 = ['has wings', 'no wings']

tuples = list(zip(array1, array2))
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

df = pd.DataFrame([['bird', 'monkey'], ['dragon','horse']])
df.columns = col


array1 = ['foo', 'foo']
array2 = ['baz', 'bar']
tuples = list(zip(array1, array2))
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['bird', 'monkey'], ['dragon','horse']])
df2.columns = col

new_df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

output:

```
     animal              foo        
  has wings no wings     baz     bar
0      bird   monkey    bird  monkey
1    dragon    horse  dragon   horse
```